# Diff syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an extension or setting, which makes a file with a `.diff` extension, opened in VS Code, display added lines in green and deleted lines in red? Currently, when I open a diff file, it displays added and deleted lines in the same color. I'm using VS Code Version: 1.37.1.

P.S. I tried [the diff extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rafaelmaiolla.diff), but it doesn't work for me.

P.P.S. I tried reloading VS Code with extensions disabled and the highlighting is still broken:

[image]

Comment: So you're talking about the background color? Because otherwise that's red and green as expected.

Comment: @Gama11 you mean the color of the + and -? Because I expect that the whole line is highlighted in green or red.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

I observed that `.diff` files are highlighted by default(without requiring any extensions), it's just that certain themes do not work well.
[image: Theme-Winter is coming]

[image: Theme-Dracula at night]

Answer (score 2):

VS Code currently have this feature, if you get the .diff extension the sintax highlight performs correctly like git bash.

My VS Code is:

```
Version: 1.47.2 (system setup)
Commit: 17299e413d5590b14ab0340ea477cdd86ff13daf
Date: 2020-07-15T18:22:06.216Z
Electron: 7.3.2
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 6.3.9600
```